# How to mask email address in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

How do I mask the email address string in Objective-C?

I want to mask email as follows

mugunth@gmail.com into m*****h@gmail.com

Comment: NSRegularExpression may help you

Comment: @GovindParashar can you provide me a code snippet for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the range of `@` and create a new range by decreasing 2 from the range location. Create a new string with `*` characters repeating by the new range length. Now replace the characters from the range.

```
NSArray *emails = @[@"mugunth@gmail.com",@"mugunthgmail.com",@"m@gmail.com"];
NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]{2,}+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
for (NSString *email in emails) {
    if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:email]) {
        NSRange range = [email rangeOfString:@"@"];
        NSRange newRange = NSMakeRange(1, range.location-2);
        NSString *replace = [@"" stringByPaddingToLength:newRange.length withString:@"*" startingAtIndex:0];
        NSString * maskedEmail = [email stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:newRange withString:replace];
        NSLog(@"%@",maskedEmail);//m*****h@gmail.com
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Invalid Email Address");
    }
}
```

> m*****h@gmail.com
>
> Invalid Email Address
>
> Invalid Email Address